# custom queries with Date input for Liferay

Tags: java, sql, database, liferay

I'm having problems in executing custom queries with Date inputs.
here's my sql:

```
<sql
     id="MyEntityFinder.findByIns">
 <![CDATA[
     SELECT {EX_MyEntity.*}
     FROM EX_MyEntity
     WHERE
         (EX_MyEntity.myDate >= ? AND EX_MyEntity.myDate <= ?)
         ]]>
</sql>
```

here's my finder MyEntityFinderImpl:

```
public class MyEntityFinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<MyEntity> implements MyEntityFinder{

    public static final String FIND_BY_INS = "MyEntityFinder.findByIns";
    public List<MyEntity> findByIns(Date from, Date to, int begin, int end) throws SystemException{
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = openSession();
        String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FIND_BY_INS);
        SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        q.setCacheable(false);
        q.addEntity("EX_MyEntity", MyEntityImpl.class);
        QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(q);  
        qPos.add("%"+from+"%");
        qPos.add("%"+to+"%");
        return (List<MyEntity>) QueryUtil.list(q, getDialect(), begin, end);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SystemException(e);
    } finally {
        closeSession(session);
    }
}
```

}

and here's how I call it from my jsp page:

```
Calendar aMonthAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
aMonthAgo.set(Calendar.MONTH, aMonthAgo.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
List<MyEntity> monthly = MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.findByIns( 
                    new java.sql.Date(aMonthAgo.getTimeInMillis()),
        new java.sql.Date(now.getTimeInMillis()), 0,
        MyEntityLocalServiceUtil.getMyEntitysCount());
```

I'm getting "java.sql.SQLException: data exception: invalid datetime format" when trying to execute the query but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

in jsp:
`Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(aMonthAgo.getTimeInMillis());`

in finder:
`qPos.add(timestamp);`

Also in the sql query I would use BETWEEN:

`WHERE DATE(EX_MyEntity.myDate) BETWEEN ? AND ?`